# How to apply java based filter with JPA pagination?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, filter, pagination

## Input request -

```
{
Page size = 20
page = 1
withIn distance 20 km;
}
```

Below is the JPA implemented method.

```
List<Hotels> hotels =  findsByHotelAddress(Address address, Pageable pageable);
```

let say, After a search, we got 20 hotels on the first page.

Now, after applying the distance filter, we got five users on the first page(1st request) and, four users on the second page(2nd request) and, six users on the third page(3rd request).

*I want to know better approach if I want to display all the fifteen filtered hotels only on the 1st page.*

FYI: Distance is calculated(using google map) based on user location and Hotel location.
The Distance field is not available in the DB column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement Specification interface . Check it out for more details 
[Specification-Properties](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification)